# css - How to display blocks of information inline

Tags: css

Don't know why I can't figure this one out myself because it feels relatively simple, I want to display two "blocks" inline. The result I want can be found below in a hyperlink (Goes to an image)

The html i have is

```css
#content-main {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>challenge 5</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="header">
    <blockquote>
      <p>Learning is not a privilege, it's a right.</p>
    </blockquote>
    <div id="logo">
      <h1>live and let learn</h1>
      <img src="img/Csschallenge5.jpg" alt="live and let learn">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <div id="content-side">
      <dl>
        <dt><a href="services/">Services</a></dt>
        <dd>Learning and facilitation through TAFE WSI</dd>

        <dt><a href="learning/">Personal Learning</a></dt>
        <dd>Learning from the network</dd>

        <dt><a href="resources/">Resources</a></dt>
        <dd>Browse through resources ...</dd>

        <dt><a href="about/">About</a></dt>
        <dd>What am I about? Personal interests and other stuff</dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
    <!-- content-side -->

    <div id="content-main">
      <h2>Please update your links!</h2>
      <small>Wednesday, October 12th, 2005</small>

      <p>New blog address: <a href="http://liveandletlearn.net/learning/">
              http://liveandletlearn.net/learning/</a>
      </p>
      <p>During the last holidays I've been busy moving my blog from
        <a href="http://www.absoludity.net/blog/">absoludity.net</a> to
        <a href="http://liveandletlearn.net/learning/">liveandletlearn.net</a> ... why? Good question! Part of the Web Design course that I facilitate is a client project where participants are required to develop a site from start to finish - and i'd
        been a while since I'd been through that process myself - so what better a project for the holidays (next to my gardening project to get me <em>away</em> from the computer)!
      </p>

      <p>You'll notice that the site itself is still in prototype stage, but the blog is all up and running so I'm going to be using liveandletlearn from now on. <strong>Please update your 
              bookmarks/feeds</strong>! And please give me any feedback you've got time for at
        <a href="http://liveandletlearn.net/learning/">liveandletlearn.net</a>!
      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- content-main -->
  </div>
  <!-- content -->

</body>

</html>
```

I don't have much css because I wasn't sure where to start, This is all I have:

```
 #content-main {
        float: right;
    }
```

I was told to use `display: inline;` or `float: right;`

It does something but not what I'm trying to achieve, I'm trying to achieve this. [Website Layout/Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxlhW.png)

I've tried researching it to no avail.
I haven't used css for quite a while now so please excuse my rustiness.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you out

```
#content-side {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#content-main {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

For better responsiveness of your design I would suggest you to use Bootstrap and it will do this kind of things with ease.

Answer (score 0):

Use css flexbox, it is pretty easy. Just update your css styles by:

```
#content {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you can use CSS flexbox. Please check it below:

```
#content {
display:flex;
}
#content-side {
width:30%; <!-- set your content-side block width as per your design -->
}
#content-main {
width:70%; <!-- set your content-main block width as per your design -->
}
```

Hope it may help you out!

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS flexbox layout. Add flex property for content-side and content-main.
flex is the shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis.

Below is the css you can try.

```
#content {
    display:flex;
}
#content-side {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
}
#content-main {
    flex: 1;
}
```